# MVC 3 App Slow on IE 8 on Windows 7, Fast on IE 8 on Windows XP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, authorization, windows-authentication

I am developing an app for my company using ASP MVC 3.0. It uses Windows Authentication to log the user in, and the `User.IsInRole` method or the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Currently, I am having issues with initial load and response times, but ONLY for users who happen to be running Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7. These users are experiencing load times of around 20 seconds. All other users have had no issues when running on Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP and experience load times of less than a second.

I'm fairly certain it is an Internet Explorer 8 issue, as downloading Google Chrome on a Windows 7 PC has instantaneous load times. The most mind boggling part though, is that I am running a Windows 7 PC and have IE 8 and am not running into these issues and have instant loading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had an similar issue and set roleManager enabled to false in the web.config. At the time it sped up site loading drastically. I can't seem to replicate it now since I moved servers. Previously the site loading would timeout and then suddenly come up after about 10 seconds.

Comment: Do the users having the issue happen to IPV6 enabled? if so try turning it off in the network adapter settings dialog,  Just Uncheck **Internet Protocol Verision 6 (TCP/IPv6)** in their adapter settings and see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: @merekel I need roleManager enabled because some users are not allowed to access the app, and some users are supposed to have limited access to functionality of the app.

Comment: @KeithLawrence I tried disabling IPV6 on both the local machine as well as the server and this did not improve the issue.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe it is just how the server is setup but using windows auth, having the role manager enabled does nothing either way.

Comment: Do you have any scripts that only run if user agent is IE7 or IE8? In IE9 or IE10, press F12 to bring up developer Tools. Set browser mode to IE8 and click the network tab and then "Start Capturing" and see if it's a slow script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was unable to figure out what the root cause of this problem was. So, I thought I would at least post the solution that I used to get around it.

Fortunately, we had a second server for hosting. I migrated over to this server and housed it there and it seemed to work fine. More than likely, the problem with the original server could be the way it was set up, installed or some type of firewall issue that we had.